# mvc 5 EditorFor Jquery Datepicker not setting value of date

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, jquery-ui-datepicker

Here is my Model:

```
public class Project{
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public System.DateTime EstEndDate { get; set; }}
```

Here is my Controller:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {   //getting model object
        Project project = dbAccessor.getProjectForProjectId(id);
        //passing to View
        return View(project);
    }
```

In my View:

```
<div>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.EstEndDate)</div>
```

This is not setting the EditorFor field with the Date value. My idea is to set the value of the JQuery Datepicker and let the user edit it if needed. I also need to get back the Date the User enters later.

But here is what is happening:

[image]

These are the things I have tried that I found on stackoverflow.:-

1) I added a Value field

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.EstEndDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" }, @Value = Model.EstEndDate})
```

This did not set the value. I can see the value in the HTML (Right click -> View Page Source) and this is what is displayed
`<div><input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field EstEndDate must be a date." data-val-required="The EstEndDate field is required." id="EstEndDate" name="EstEndDate" type="date" value="04/15/2016" /></div>`

So the value is being entered but not displaying on the JQuery DatePicker.

2)I replaced EditorFor with TextBoxFor and this is displaying the value but now I cant select Jquery DatePicker widget to select a different date. See pic

[image]

Please help me fix this.

Comment: It needs to be `DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}"` (ISO format) for use with the browsers HTML-5 datepicker (and its only supported in Chrome and Edge)

Comment: And never try to set the `value` attribute when using the `HtmlHelper` methods.

Comment: The first image in your question is a `HTML-5` datapicker (and its generated because your have `[DataType(DataType.Date)]` and the use of `EditorFor()` adds `type="date"`). You have not indicated which jquery datepicker you want to use or shown the code for how you are attaching the plugin to the element.

Comment: this worked - DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}"
Do you want to add as an answer so I can mark it correct?

Comment: No need - I have already marked it as a duplicate :)